# Why does VMware Player/Ubuntu use such a large resolution by default?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, display, resolution

I created a new VM and began installing Ubuntu, and the VM's screen is strangely enormous, requiring much vertical and horizontal scrolling.

I didn't change any of the VM's settings. The display setting is showing Monitors:

- Use host settings for monitors (selected)
- Number of monitors: 1
- Maximum resolution of any one monitor: 2560 x 1600

When I right-click my Windows desktop and select Screen resolution, it says it's 1280 x 800. Apparently VMware Player is getting wrong information about my screen resolution.

[image: Screenshot]

Specs:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- VMware Player 3.1.3
- Windows 7 Professional x64
- MacBook Pro 2009

I also posted this in [VMware Communities](http://communities.vmware.com/message/2117011).